# Can't use Excel dll on AppHarbor

Tags: excel, appharbor

I'm having trouble with uploading an excel file to AppHarbor and then opening it, even though it works fine locally. I am uploading the file to App_Data and have the AppHarbor settings set to write to file directory. The file actually is uploaded ok (I think), however when I try to use the Excel dll:

```
var excel = new Application();
```

It generates this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

I have a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in my project, and even tried copying it locally and referencing it there. Any ideas?

Comment: Is Excel installed in AppHarbor?  I'm guessing not, since MS specifically recommends against doing that...

Comment: Excel is not installed on AppHarbor application servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Interop libraries only serve as an interface to the Excel application, which must be installed wherever your code is running.  Seems it's not available on AppHarbor.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to change my app to only accept csv upload.